# Subquery for simple addition?

Tags: sql-server

I'm using the Northwind sample database.

**PROBLEM**: show the product names for products that have been ordered in quantities equal to or exceeding 120. Use a non-correlated subquery in the SQL statement.

Question: how can I write this as a non-correlated subquery? This simple statement I created produces the correct results:

```
SELECT [ProductName] 
FROM Products
WHERE ([UnitsInStock] + [UnitsOnOrder] > = 120)
```

My use of a subquery results in error.  This is my best attempt:

```
SELECT [ProductName]
FROM [dbo].[Products]
WHERE 120 < = 
    (SELECT [UnitsInStock] + [UnitsOnOrder]
        FROM Products)
```

Error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you understand WHY your query does not work? You know that the subquery returns multiple rows. The problem with your usage is that you cannot compare a scalar value to a logical table (the resultset of your query). This is a very common mistake.

I believe that this is the most likely solution intended for your exercise. The derived table solution (posted first) is not really a subquery.

```
select prd.ProductName 
from dbo.Products as prd
where prd.ID in (select px.ID from dbo.Products as px 
    where px.UnitsInStock + px.UnitsOnOrder > = 120)
order by ...;
```

Some things to note.

- You should always schema-qualify your object names.
- Though subjective, IMO you should avoid adding square brackets as object name delimiters when they are not needed. That just makes your code more difficult to read.
- Generally resultsets should be ordered. I added the clause but left it unfinished.
- Get in the good habit of using statement terminators. Eventually they will be required.
- I have no idea what the primary key is for the Products table but I assumed it is not the name column. I guessed it was ID - replace as necessary. Name might be an acceptable alternative if it is declared as unique and not nullable.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response!

 "The problem with your usage is that you cannot compare a scalar value to a logical table (the resultset of your query)."  This explanation set me in the right direction to finding the solution to this odd problem. 

Thank you for all your additional notes!  Very informative.

Comment: I disagree with your third bullet point. If you have a clustered index the result set will always be ordered NOT to mention adding extra overhead to a query is a waste of CPU resources. If it doesnt need to be ordered, then why bother?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having is that you haven't realized that SQL can be declarative - you can pretty much select from ANYTHING, you just have to get used to how to do it.

Also the error you're getting is you're treating you where clause sub query as correlated.

Check this:

```
SELECT ProductName 
FROM
    (
        SELECT [ProductName] 
        FROM Products p
        WHERE ([UnitsInStock] + [UnitsOnOrder] > = 120)
    ) x
```

Comment: LOL 

Yea HW is going a little slow at the moment and this one was bugging me!  THANK YOU!

Understanding that a subquery can exist in the SELECT, FROM, and WHERE clauses, I did experiment but not without a table in the outer query.

Comment: @NoobMaster if this solved it for you, make sure to mark as answered. I love delicious feedbax

Answer (score -1):

Okay, so you are on the right path. The question is from the A set give me the set b with an order quantity equal or greater than 120. So your A set will only be products. the b set will be the products with quantity ordered >=120

Select product from A where productid in ( select productid from b where b.quantity >=120)

A is the product table,
b is your orders table where the product and quantity are been associated.

you can use the IN operator to filter the A set